# read() from socket need an extra enter every time ( C-programming a remote shell )

Tags: c, shell, client, server, stdout

I have a problem when using commands in my remote shell. Everytime I use a command like ls or pwd or something else I have to press enter or something else for an result to appear for the client. I assume it has something to do with buffering or filedescriptors but I  tried anything and cant get it to work properly. On the serverside the result is visible instantly. It feels like my client is stuck in the previous "round".

So this is what my server does when a connection was found.

```
pid_t pid, wpid;
int status;

pid = fork();

if (pid > 0) {
/* Thats the Parent */
    longjmp(bufferB,1);
} else if (pid == 0) {
/* Thats the Child */

    dup2(cli_sock, STDOUT_FILENO);

    while (1) {

        /* prepare buffer */
        memset(buf, 0, BUF_SIZE);

        /* get request */
        ret = read(cli_sock, buf, BUF_SIZE - 1); /* -1: '\0' ending */

        if (ret < 0)
            term("Couldn't read from socket");

        /* handle no input, e.g. client exit during open connection */
        if (ret == 0)
            break;

        /* handle request */
        lsh_loop(buf);

        if (!strcmp("exit", buf))
            break;

        if (ret < 0)
            term("Couldn't write to socket");
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "A Connection was closed!\n");
}

/* clean up */
term(NULL);

return EXIT_SUCCESS;}
```

This is what my client does after connecting.

```
    while (1) {
    /* get user command */
    ret = getline(&cmd, &cmd_sz, stdin);

    if (ret < 0)
        term("Couldn't get command from user");

    buf[ret] = '\0';

    /* send command request to server */
    ret = write(sock, buf, ret);

    if (ret < 0)
        term("Couldn't write to socket");

    /* exit if required */
    if (!strcmp("exit\n", buf))
        break;

    /* get server response */
    memset(buf, 0, BUF_SIZE);

    ret = recv(sock, buf, BUF_SIZE - 1, MSG_EOR); /* -1 for '\0' ending */

    if (ret < 0)
        term("Couldn't read from socket");

    /* output response */
    printf("%s", buf);
    fflush(stdout);


}

term(NULL);

return EXIT_SUCCESS;}
```

And here is a little Sample from the shell.

```
void lsh_loop(char *line) {
char prompt_puffer[200];
char **args;
int status;

setjmp(bufferA);
if (getcwd(prompt_puffer, sizeof(prompt_puffer)) == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "lsh: no directory found");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
strcat(prompt_puffer, "$  ");

args = lsh_split_line(line);
status = lsh_execute(args);
/* Using a status variable returned by lsh_execute() to determine when to exit */
fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", prompt_puffer);
printf("%s", prompt_puffer);
fflush(stdout);}
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You're making it take input from the command line before it can receive information from the port with `ret = getline(&cmd, &cmd_sz, stdin);`. Either change the order for the client if you want to read port data and **then** accept command line input, or even better: give the client a "reading thread" that will constantly read, print, and loop.